# How do I order a mixed text and integer field in a pivot table in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-apps

Let's say that we have two columns on a sheet:

```
Name     Room
-------------
Steve    A1
Jill     A1
Sam      A1
Steve    A2
...
Lisa     A10
Sally    A11
Jim      A11
```

My actual dataset has up to a hundred of these rooms.

The issue I'm running into is with pivot tables. When I want to get a list of rooms and the count (counta is the one I'm using) it works, but the order is not what I wanted. It comes out as:

```
Room     Count
--------------
A1       3
A10      1
A11      2
...
A2       1
```

I guess I can kind of see why it would be doing that. I'd much rather have it list it out in order. A1, A2, A3... A10, A11, A12, etc.

Is there an easy way to do this without some sort of data manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

An "easy" way to do this without "data manipulation" is to copy the PT, Paste special, Paste values only and then drag the relevant rows (presumably at most only 8) to where you want them. The easiest way is probably with "data manipulation", for example:

```
=if(len(A1)=2,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"A","A0"),A1)
```

(Though in you case, whichever column would be the right one, it would not be ColumnA.)

Comment: So I just worked a little more with it, and still can't get it to work. I even got a formula to parse out the string into two columns, so you have the room letter in one, and the room number part in another. Then tried to create a pivot table and trying to sort by the number, and it still does it! Made sure the data type is integer, still the same behavior!

Then I ran into this (https://plus.google.com/116901915607182586367/posts/i6jNGxZyzRa) from 2011, saying they had the same problem. Could it be true this is still an issue? I don't want to copy/paste because the number of rooms changes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you transform the string elements into number values using a lookup table.
I've created a sample spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ky_7_do4UlAagnhvK2QphYnQdrLASC-bt1mqDnPVd8/edit#gid=0).

1. The input data in the 'input' sheet has the keys as you described.
2. The next sheet is the "lookup table" to translate each key into a value number. I suggest choosing large numbers to leave room for future intermediate numbers if needed
3. Pivot 1 is based on the original data as you described
4. Pivot 2 is based on the re-calculated room name using the lookup table.

The formula I used for the re-calculation is:
`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,MID(A2,1,1),VLOOKUP(MID(A2,1,1),'Lookup table'!$A$1:$B$2,2)))`

I was a little lazy with the string lookup in the original name (`MID`), assuming your string is the first character and is 1 character long. This can be mended specifically with pattern matching.